# "Announce the time" not working in macOS monterey 12.5.1

Tags: macos, monterey, accessibility, time

"Announce the time" not working in macOS monterey 12.5.1 - I have ADHD and relied on this feature alot to stop me "losing time". I can see the settings and options and they are enabled but I cannot even "play" the voice when setting it up in "customise voice" even when all the voice options are downloaded and any of one of them selected (have tried them all). The voice doesn't announce the time at all anymore since the update. Please help?

[image]

Comment: Do you have sound set to off?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. If I restart the computer or gets put to sleep. The computer seems to stop announcing the time. However if I go and uncheck/recheck the announce time, it starts to work. Just try to keep that in mind until this get a long term fix but its been months and still am seeing this issue :/